# How to solve this problem using the Maximum matching algorithm for general graph?

Tags: bipartite-matching

For any general graph G(V,E) , the maximum matching can be calculated in O(√V.|E|) time using the following algorithm :

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221499631_An_Osqrtv_E_Algorithm_for_Finding_Maximum_Matching_in_General_Graphs

The following problem has 5-parts : -

1)Calculate maximum matching of Graph G

Can Tutte Matrix be used here ?

2)Calculate maximum matching of Graph G1 where G1 is the Line-Graph of graph G

3)Calculate maximum matching of Graph G2 where G2 is the Line-Graph of graph G1

4)Calculate maximum matching of Graph G3 where G3 is the Line-Graph of graph G2

5)Calculate maximum matching of Graph G4 where G4 is the Line-Graph of graph G3

Part-1 can be solved using the algorithm above.

My approach for solving part-2 is to construct G1 and then apply the algorithm on it , same for G2,G3,G4 , but the problem is that number of nodes and edges increase a lot in G1,G2,G3,G4 , if say , G has 3000 nodes and same number of edges, G3 might have more than 108/109 nodes and edges , so I cannot construct such a large graph as it will be inefficient in time and space to do it . How can solve the remaining parts efficiently ?

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X97001039

Comment: Thanks.... But I did not understand the meaning of 2-chain graph cover as they mentioned in the article. Can you answer it here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3613889/meaning-of-2-chain-cover-of-a-graph or explain me in the comments.

Comment: I believe it's just a path of length 2 (edges).

Comment: But what is the exact meaning of "2-chain-graph-cover" . So confusing :(

Comment: All of these concepts, including 2-chain, are defined in the paper.

Comment: Ok, so this is what I understood : - They are asking for the maximum edge cover of the graph such that any chain in the edge cover has lenght <=2 , am I correct ?

Comment: They are just rephrasing what a matching in the line graph is in terms of the original graph. With that in mind, you should be able to work out the correct definition on your own. Otherwise, it's spelled out in the paper.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/123726/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3612906/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: This seems like too many questions for one post.

Comment: This question is very similar to a problem from an ongoing contest, which ends on 13th April: https://www.codechef.com/APRIL20A/problems/LLLGRAPH. It would be very helpful if the community refrains from discussing the solution of this problem till the 13th, so as to maintain fairness of the contest.